# WHERE x IN (1,2,3,4) workflow

Tags: mysql, sql, excel

I am looking for a streamlined way to create a WHERE IN query that searches for a few dozen new IN values each week. We get the IN values in .xls format, and are looking for a way to get commas in between each number so we can just cut and paste the values inside the parenthesis.

Comment: Save the XLS as CSV?  Otherwise, you'll need to indicate in what language your application is coded.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Once I save as CSV, how do I expose the commas?

Comment: Read the contents of the file.

Comment: When I open the file there are no comma's in the cells, just the numbers in column A. PIBKAC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The other possible way is

1. Just copy the Entire colomn from Excel
2. paste it in some
   advanced Textpad say Notepad++, TextPad, Editplus
3. create a macro
   in it, you can enough help in online in order to create a macro(Only
   one time effort)
4. now run the created macro

This approach will certainly helps you in many other repeatable tasks.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how the values are in the Excel sheet. You could export them as CSV and have and copy them afterwards. Or you could also use some VBA in order to have script you can execute. This script might also execute the query so that you don't need to execute anything by yourself. But this also depends on your experiences with VBA.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Once I save as CSV, how do I expose the commas?

Comment: I'm missing something. I open it Excel 2003 and the values are displayed in column a but there are no comma's the cells. I also opened it in notepad, no comma's just the numbers on top of each other.

Comment: You may have to transpose the values then before you export them so that they are in one row. Or another solution could be to replace all line endings with a comma.